# Symfony\Process package in Laravel (for python files)

Tags: php, python, laravel, symfony, symfony-process

I am trying to run python files in Laravel Project.Therefore, i use the Symfony\Process package.My code looks like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

$process = new Process(["python","C:\xampp\htdocs\backend\Scrape\AnnouncementsScrape.py"]);
$process->run();
```

When i use this line:

```
throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
```

my laravel project returns error (I use laravel framework for my backend in my mobile app, so i can not see the exactly error; i can only see that there is problem with my backend)

Το sum up, i run the code above, but the Process is not successfull.
I check it with the condition:

```
if ($process->isSuccessful())
```

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Although the process may not be successful, it still produces an output, which you can access.

You can use `$process->getOutput()` and `$process->getErrorOutput()` for that